# Facebook OAuth: custom callback_uri parameters

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I'd like to have a dynamic redirect URL for my Facebook OAuth2 integration.  For example, if my redirect URL is this in my Facebook app:

```
http://www.mysite.com/oauth_callback?foo=bar
```

I'd like the redirect URL for a specific request be something like this, so that on the server, I have some context about how to process the auth code:

```
http://www.mysite.com/oauth_callback?foo=bar&user=6234
```

My redirect gets invoked after the authorization dialog is submitted, and I get back an auth code, but when I try to get my access token, I'm getting an OAuthException error back from Facebook.  My request looks like this (line breaks added for clarity):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
    ?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Foauth_callback%3Ffoo%3Dbar%26user%3D6234
    &client_secret=MY_SECRET
    &code=RECEIVED_CODE
```

All of my parameters are URL-encoded, and the code looks valid, so my only guess is that the problem parameter is my redirect_uri.  I've tried setting `redirect_uri` to all of the following, to no avail:

1. The actual URL of the request to my site
2. The URL of the request to my site, minus the `code` parameter
3. The URL specified in my Facebook application's configuration

Are custom redirect URI parameters supported?  If so, am I specifying them correctly?  If not, will I be forced to set a cookie, or is there some better pattern for supplying context to my web site?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I figured out the answer; rather than adding additional parameters to the redirect URL, you can add a `state` parameter to the request to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
    ?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
    &scope=MY_SCOPE
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Foauth_callback%3Ffoo%3Dbar
    &state=6234
```

That state parameter is then passed to the callback URL.

Comment: But state parameter can only contains number characters, isn't it?

Comment: No, it can contain any arbitrary data.  At the time I wrote this, I was putting a whole JSON object in that parameter (URL-encoded, of course).

Comment: The state is intended for a random unguessable hash to prevent CSRF. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Interesting, their documentation didn't make mention that it was for CSRF originally. However, this doesn't change the fact that it seems to be the only way they give to pass arbitrary data. I suppose you could make your state parameter a JSON structure containing both a nonce and your state data, or the nonce only to use for looking up the rest of the information.

Comment: Great Answer..! I used this for facebook. But how do we do the same for twitter. It is not working :(

Comment: Perhaps a bit old, but the state param is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

Comment: Why should I store custom redirect params in `state`?

Comment: auth0 allows extra query params in callback urls, but sadly facebook and twitter don't :(

Answer (score 12):

If, for any reason, you can't use the option that Jacob suggested as it's my case, you can **urlencode** your `redirect_uri` parameter before passing it and it will work, even with a complete querystring like `foo=bar&morefoo=morebar` in it.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: It used to work for me this way and then just stopped; now "sharing" the `state` parameter for both XSRF protection as well as my own ID is the solution for me.

Comment: This does not work anymore, at least not in my case. It is only returning the first query string parameter when redirecting back from authentication.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to implement a Facebook login workflow against API v2.9 following [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow). I tried the solutions described above. Manuel's answer is sort of correct, but what I observed is url encoding is not needed. Plus, you can only pass one parameter. Only the first query parameter will be considered, the rest will be ignored. Here is an example,

1. Request a code via `https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri=http://{url}/login-redirect?myExtraParameter={some-value}`
2. You'd get a callback for your url. It will look like `http://{url}/login-redirect?code={code-from-facebook}&myExtraParameter={value-passed-in-step-1}`. Note that facebook would make a callback with `myExtraParameter`. You can extract the value for `myExtraParameter` from callback url.
3. Then you can request access token with `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/oauth/access_token?client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&code={code-from-facebook}&redirect_uri=http://{url}/login-redirect?myExtraParameter={value-extracted-in-step-2}`

Additional parameter passed in step 1 after the first query parameter will be ignored. Also make sure to not include any invalid characters in your query parameter (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query) for more information).

Comment: Maybe the Facebook server is being forgiving, but you absolutely should URL-encode `redirect_uri`; it is not valid to have an unencoded second `?` in the URL nor `&`s, since it makes the parameter list ambiguous. If you URL-encode, you don't have to worry about avoiding "invalid characters" in the parameter. Your additional parameters are probably "ignored" because of your lack of encoding `&` (how could it differentiate between it being a parameter separator or part of `callback_uri` otherwise?)

Comment: @mert I have added my callback url in ` Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` of Facebook login product under `Client OAuth Settings` without adding additional parameters. It is not working in my case `URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.`

Answer (score -1):

You're best off specifying a unique callback for each oAuth provider, `/oauth/facebook`, `/oauth/twitter` etc.

If you really want the same file to respond to all oAuth requests, either include it in the individual files or setup a path that will call the same file on your server using .htaccess redirects or something similar: `/oauth/*` > `oauth_callback.ext`

Answer (score -1):

You should set your custom `state` parameter using the login helper as such:

```php
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => env('FB_APP_ID'),
    'app_secret' => env('FB_APP_SECRET'),
    'default_graph_version' => env('FB_APP_VER'),
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = [
    'public_profile',
    'user_link',
    'email',
    'read_insights',
    'pages_show_list',
    'instagram_basic',
    'instagram_manage_insights',
    'manage_pages'
];

$random = Str::random(20);

$OAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

$redirectLoginHelper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$persistentDataHandler = $redirectLoginHelper->getPersistentDataHandler();

$persistentDataHandler->set('state', $random);

$loginUrl = $OAuth2Client->getAuthorizationUrl(
        url('/') . '/auth/facebook',
        $random,
        $permissions
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey if you are using official facebook php skd then you can set custom `state` param like this

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state',"any_data");
$url = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback_url, $fb_permissions_array);
```