# Scribe - multiple callback simultaneously

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, callback, scribe

I am making a module for a server software that is allowing support for facebook.
The problem is with the callback URL. If one client start the authorization proccess, then another client starts the proccess at the same time, or before the first user finish. How could I check what user finished first?

I need a way to check what client's callback I'm getting. One solution would be to lock other from register until the first one has finished, but I don't want to do that. Is there another way? I have thought about including `?client=clientid` at the end of the callback, but I heard facebook only allows the exact url specified in the app on facebook.

**UPDATE**
It didn't work to add client="clientid" to the callback. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searchig I figured facebook will allow a parameter: state. (thanks to @jacob https://stackoverflow.com/a/6470835/1104307)

So I just did ?state=clientId.

For anyone using scribe the code is this:

```
service.getAuthorizationUrl(null) + "&state=" + clientId;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem on adding and GET parameter like client=clientID. Facebook will redirect you to the URL you have specified and using the REQUEST parameters you can check who completed the request. The problem exist if you have specified URL as http://yoursite.com and pass redirect to http://some-sub-domain.yoursite.com or entirely different location.

Comment: So i'll just do?

    .callback(callbackURL+"?client="+clientId)

Comment: that didn't work well..:    
`{
"error":{
    "message" : "Error validating verification code. Please make    sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
    "type" : "OAuthException",
    "code" : 100
}
}`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the server-side flow then the oauth 2 flow will be:

1. redirect user to facebook
2. facebook then rediects the user to your specified callback
3. your server uses something like curl to get the access token
4. your server does some more curl to get maybe more user data or update the user's data

my recommendation would be to set a session cookie in step 1 and simultaneously store this session id on your server. then the session cookie will automatically be sent to the callback url in step 2 and you can identify the session in the database this way.

this will work for all service providers (google, twitter, linkedin, etc) and is the preferred way of maintaining session continuity.

Comment: Ok, But how should I go for adding the sessionCookie?

Comment: if you are using php you can use the `setcookie` function, if you are using javascript you would use `document.cookie`.