# How do I submit and process request params with an Oauth request?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, express, oauth, meanjs

I am using the MeanJS stack to develop a web application. The issue I'm having, is that my regular signup process has some unique parameters that are not common to an Oauth user profile. So, when I have the user go to signup with facebook, I move them to a new Signup form, that has them fill in the extra parameters, and then click "signup with facebook."

The routes are the same as the common MeanJS routes found here: 
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/routes/users.server.routes.js

Specifically these lines:

```
app.route('/auth/facebook').get(passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['email']
}));

app.route('/auth/facebook/callback').get(users.oauthCallback('facebook'));
```

What I would like to do, is have the extra parameters attached to the request object, so that when the auth process reaches the `exports.saveOAuthUserProfile` inside of: https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/controllers/users/users.authentication.server.controller.js
this function will be able to access those parameters and save them as part of the user model.

I have tried attaching parameters to the Get request and accessing

`req.params.paramId`

but this will not work, because you cannot register a param loaded request with the facebook api (or at least it seems to be that way).

And I have read elsewhere on StackOverflow that you can load the request State, but that seems really odd to me. Here's the link for that: [Facebook OAuth: custom callback_uri parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463152/facebook-oauth-custom-callback-uri-parameters)

So, any guidance on how to load the extra data into the Oauth request, so that when I save the user profile I can access it and save it, would be great.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you want to achieve. What are the "extra" fields, and why don't you derive the fields from the user's profile directly?. About 98% of the FB Login implementations I've seen just use the "Login with Facebook" button and get the user's data during the OAuth process itself, and not manually entered by the user.

With [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) for example, it's possible that you

a) Configure custom scopes

- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#extended-permissions

b) Enrich the profile object with the custom scope's data

- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#profile-fields

The `profile` object will then contain the additional requested fields automatically, and you don't need to tweak the request object itself.

Comment: The purpose is that the user is specifying some custom data that is not part of the Facebook profile system at all, yet it is data that is a part of this system's user object (and a requirement for signup). So, I want the user to be able to enter in this extra data on signup, even with Facebook.

Comment: Combine both FB profile and custom valued in a session object.