# Handling illegal query string parameter names in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a client that is sending me a query string where several of the parameters begin with a dollar (`$`) sign. I can't start my parameters' names in C# with `$`, which means that the values are not mapping when my action is being called.

Before anyone asks, no I cannot have the client change the name of the query string.

I have a feeling I'm going to have to write some sort of custom action filter to find these parameters, rename them and then pass them on to the correct action. But, before I did all that, I wanted to post the question here to see if there's a solution I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of web api?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I handled the issue:

```
    [HttpGet, Route("myResource")]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult GetThings()
    {
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
        var queryParam = query["$myParam"];

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, $ should not be used as part of the parameter names, as it is reserved in the URI definition

[What does dollar sign $ do in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050114/what-does-dollar-sign-do-in-url)

So the query string you are receiving is formally incorrect, and the best solution would be to change it, as future Http implementations or even some firewalls may break your solution.

A work around would be to override the query string parser, and access the URI directly, using HttpRequest properties Url (maybe the query method) or RawUrl:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This news will come as a huge shock to the odata folks

Comment: Agree... I was with a team that was part of defining OData some 10 years ago, and this was raised but didn't progress.