# Why doesn't HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues("key") recognize semicolon as a delimiter?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, query-string

I'm stumped. I thought `&` AND `;` were valid delimiters for a query parameter.

It seems that tomcat 7 `HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues("key")` won't recognize my parameter when it is like this:

```
http://acme.com/my.jsp?x=1;y=2;z=3
```

If I go here, there is mention of the semi-colon:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Is there a way to force tomcat 7 to recognize them within this method? Or is there a better method to use?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending that URL from within HTML and outside a `<form>...</form>`?

Comment: Link to relevant w3.org "Performance, Implementation, and Design Notes", [B.2.2 Ampersands in URI attribute values](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2)

Comment: Sort of previously answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7287629/775715

Comment: `;` may have been supported in the 90s, but its time to do it right and use `&`.

Comment: I agree with @developerwjk - The `;` recommendation is really just to get around concerns in SGML anyway.

Comment: So the answer is, that it is just a minor note within the RFC and not supported in all backend frameworks and not supported at all within HTML 5.  Thanks to everyone who commented.

Comment: It apparently was supported in Tomcat 5.5.25; just checked an old server I have.

Comment: And that explains a lot. We moved from tomcat 5.5 to tomee plus that is probably the 2nd version of tomee plus to come out. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @D-Klotz that note is not part of an IETF RFC, its merely a set of recommendations by the w3 (different organization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For closure, this is the bug report outlining why tomcat 7 does not recognize a semicolon as a separator within the query parameter

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39740

The last comment before it was marked as "won't fix" is that this can be resolved by implementing a custom filter. Which is of course true.

Thanks to everyone who responded.