# Passing DateTimeOffset to WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

My WebAPI method looks like this:

```
[Route("api/v1.0/Profile/Test/{offset}")]
public async Task<ServiceResult> GetTest(DateTimeOffset offset)
{
...
}
```

Calling it like this works:
http://localhost:54295/api/v1.0/Profile/Test/2016-04-05T13:30:44-11:00

However, this call won't work:
http://localhost:54295/api/v1.0/Profile/Test/2016-04-05T13:30:44+11:00

What's the trick here?

In my Web.config in the `system.web` section I have this entry:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,*,\,?" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing DateTimeOffset as WebAPI query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549737/passing-datetimeoffset-as-webapi-query-string)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

In my `web.config` in the `system.webServer` section I added this block:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```

Now the plus sign works as desired.