# REST URL request and square brackets ('[' and ']')

Tags: rest, parameters, character, standards

I would like to know if square brackets (`[` and `]`) are standard in REST URL parameters.

1. I have to call a Cloud REST WebService by settings all parameters in the URL. The URL looks like: `https://DNS_SERVEUR/api/2/conversation?filters[website]=1234&data=a0123....`

   You can see that one parameter's name contains square brackets: `filters[website]`
2. Calling the URL directly with Firefox or SOAP-UI does not raise any issue (they do not crash on square brackets).

   However, using Oracle Fusion Middleware 12.2.1.1.0 and dedicated REST adapter, I have an error: square bracket characters are not allowed in parameter name.

So here is my question: Can square bracket characters (`[` and `]`) be used as standard REST URL parameters? Or is it a limitation in Oracle Fusion Middleware?

I searched on the Internet and did not get any clear answer. The only example (in French) using it is to manipulate associative array in PHP: http://cyberzoide.developpez.com/php4/url/#LII-E. As PHP is very permissive, I do not take it has a reliable reference for standard.

Comment: There is some example of good and bad URL patterns here : http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

But nothing about '[' and ']' parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RFC 3986 should be the go-to for understanding what is allowed in the [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) of a URI.

```
query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

Hook characters are `gen-delims`, not `sub-delims`

```
gen-delims    = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
```

So they should be encoded when appearing in the query part.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375597/54734

Comment: Thank you, it answer my question. Those caracters are legit as delimiter but it is up to parsing algorithm to decide to use them (or not).
At https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2, it says : "These characters are called
   "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
   the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
   implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm".
It seems in my case, the algorithm decided to ban those charaters

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is to way to manage REST WebService and it influence the characters allowed in URL :

1. Without any description language, then there no rule to controle your URI exept what HTTP protocole allows. So, refering to VoiceOfUnreason's response, [] characters are allowed but there interpretation is depending to the server application
2. With a WADL description language (the equivalent of WSDL but for REST). The dedicated RFC ([Web Application Description Language](https://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/#x3-270002.12.2)) tells parameter's name must respect NMTOKEN schema. And if you look at NMTOKEN definition ([xsd:NMTOKEN](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_NMTOKEN.html)), it does not allow [].

Yet Oracle Fusion Middleware use WADL with REST, it is natural it does not allow [] characters in REST parameter's name.