# Firebase function - http get parameters with acentuation

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function doing a http GET. There are 3 parameters and all works ok but if one of the parameters contains acentuation the Firebase console don't show any error but the the GET is not executed. In this case, the problem is with Parameter03.

```
        var url = 'http://myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/values?Parameter01=' + nameParam + '&Parameter02=' + emailParam + '&Parameter03=' + serviceParam ;

http.get(url, (resp) => {
     res.setEncoding('utf8');
}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error : " + err.message);
});
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you build a URL, you should properly escape all the query string components so that they contain [only valid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query).  That's what [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is for.  So do [encode all your query string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript) like this instead:

```
var url = 'http://myapi.azurewebsites.net/api/values' +
    '?Parameter01=' + encodeURIComponent(nameParam) +
    '&Parameter02=' + encodeURIComponent(emailParam) +
    '&Parameter03=' + encodeURIComponent(serviceParam);
```

There are other cleaner ways to build a URL with query string components, but this should work fine.

Comment: Thank you Doug. Worked. Another alternative is to clean the parameters before like in const serviceParam = servicoParamComAcentos.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")