# Radio Button Not Getting Fetched From DB

Tags: php, mysql

I know somebody already answered this but for some reason their given syntax is not working for me. I am trying to fetch a radio button value from the database and display it in a radio button too. I watched many tutorials and red threads about this but it's still not working. ***Can you guys double check what is wrong with my code? Thank you.***

This is how I fetch the `value`.

```
<label>2-3 meters
    <input type="radio" name="meter" value="2-3 Meters"
       <?php 
       if($ssh== "2-3 Meters"){
          echo "checked"; }
       ?>>
</label>

<label>1-2 meters
    <input type="radio" name="meter" value="1-2 Meters"
       <?php 
       if($ssh== "1-2 Meters"){
          echo "checked"; }
       ?>>
</label>

<label>< 1 meter
    <input type="radio" name="meter" value="< 1 Meter"
       <?php 
       if($ssh== "< 1 Meter"){
          echo "checked"; }
       ?>>
</label>
```

And this is my `PHP`

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");

$edit=$_GET['id'];
$select="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$edit'";
$run=mysqli_query($con,$select);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);

$id = "";
$ssh = "";

if(isset($_GET['ssh'])){
  $ssh = $_GET['ssh'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$_GET['ssh']` is being passing through the URL and it is being encoded, for example:

Your given value `1-2 Meters` (?ssh=1-2 Meters) will looks like `1-2%20Meters` (?ssh=1-2%20Meters) when you retrieve it on the `PHP` by using `$_GET['ssh']`. Note the `%20` characters intead the space, it happens because space is not a valid URL character. See: [What's valid and what's not in a URI query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query)

So you should decode it before assign to `$ssh` variable.

```
if(isset($_GET['ssh'])){
  $ssh = urldecode($_GET['ssh']);
}
```

To fetch the values from the database and loop the radio buttons, it should be:

```
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
?>
     <label><?php echo $row['title']; //whatever row name is on your database ?>
       <input type="radio" name="meter" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"
       <?php 
       if($ssh == $row['title']){
          echo "checked"; }
       ?>>
     </label>
<?php } ?>
```

See docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thank you for telling me that. However, your reply doesn't answer my question :(

Comment: Sadly it only hid my radio buttons. Maybe I putted it in on a wrong place? I erased my code above and changed it with your code instead.

Comment: Do not erase your code... remove `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);` and put my code... also move `$ssh = "";

if(isset($_GET['ssh'])){
  $ssh = $_GET['ssh'];
}` before my code.... You need to provide more information, like PHP erros or so

Comment: Okay so it is now working but the problem is, it only prints the value and doesn't checked the radio button. I need the radio button to be checked too. @caiovisk

Comment: When you need to have the radio button checked?? again, provide more information

Comment: So there are 3 radio buttons. Say it's `rb1`, `rb2` and `rb3`. When the value from the db is `rb1` I want the radio button that have a value of `rb1` to be checked.

Comment: This line is doing the job: `<?php 
       if($ssh == $row['title']){
          echo "checked"; }
       ?>>`... So are you passing value to `$_GET['ssh']` through the URL? Like yoururl.com?ssh=rb1

Comment: I am trying to update a table using PHP and that is the reason why I want to fetch data from the db and display it. This is how my form looks like `<form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post">`

Comment: You are using `method="post"` on your `form` and retrieving as `$_GET` on your `php`... Either you change your form `method` to `get` or change your `php` code to `$_POST['id']` instead of `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Will it still be able to update if the form method is `get`? Anyway, the button is still not checked :( I'm getting stressed.

Comment: Are you using $_GET['ssh']  or $_GET['id'] ?... You are not passing the `ssh` via `GET`