# Unity 2019 - UnityWebRequest error loading texture with space and plus on path

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, unitywebrequest

I'm using Unity 2019 and I made a script that load a texture from the pc with "UnityWebRequest".

```
using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(finalPath))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get downloaded asset bundle
            horizImg.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            horizImg.texture =  DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
        }
    }
```

If finalpath has a space or a "+" in the name it works well, but if "finalPath" has both ("+" and a space") it returns this error:

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: it can not have a space .. that's probably the main issue. You could try using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(finalPath)` though I remember that also `UnityWebRequest` should do some url encoding but not sure .. Could you show how exactly you build your path?

Comment: Also have a look at [What's valid and what's not in a URI query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand but if I use it for loading a local file it could be that there is a file with a "reserved   character"  in the name. Is there a way to escape that characters?


my path (for a local file) is built like this:  
finalPath = "file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + name;

Comment: never use string concatenation (`+ "/"`). Try using `Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, name)` instead. Also not sure but if this is Android you might need a prefix like `jar:file//`

Comment: I tried using path.combine but it's the same. For example "a+.jpg" and "a a.jpg" both work but if I use as a filename "a a+.jpg" it doesn't work.
Also I can't use   "System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()" even if I put using System.Web on top. It says "The type name 'HttpUtility' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Web'"