# WebClient uri, how to handle special characters like %

Tags: java, spring, uri, webclient

I am having a problem with WebClient when setting the queryparams. This is the code:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(config.getOAuth2Url());

        return webClient.post()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/oauth/authorize")
                        .queryParam(RESPONSE_TYPE, request.getResponse_type())
                        .queryParam(CLIENT_ID, request.getClient_id())
                        .queryParam(REDIRECT_URI, request.getRedirect_uri()) // pay attention here
                        .build())
                .header("cookie", jSessionId)
                .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(JsonNode.class)
                .block();
```

The thing is that

```
request.getRedirect_uri()
```

is a String with % characters, like this:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fbra...
```

And I am getting a 400 error because WebClient is changing in some step this String with:

```
https%253A%252F%252Fbra
```

Of course if I try a curl with my original value it works, and if I try the curl with the modified string I get a 400. How can I change WebClient behavior so it doesn't modify my url?

Comment: So you are passing an already quoted value to a method that takes a parameter that isn't quoted?  (Which `WebClient` - spring, apache, something else?)

Comment: I am passing a string which contains the % character ("https%3A%2F%5D....findestring") and every %NUMBER is being modified to %25NUMBER as I showed above.

Comment: As for which webclient, I am using spring -> https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-boot-starter-webflux%22%20AND%20g%3A%22org.springframework.boot%22

Comment: Yes - so you are supplying something already pre-quoted to `queryParam()` - but according to examples out there <https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.springframework.web.util.UriBuilder/queryParam> you need the unquoted value.  Maybe there's an alternate method which allows you to indicate its "already quoted" - otherwise need the unquoted value.

Comment: Think about it - if it didn't quote things and one of your methods returned a value with & or ? or # in it what would it do to the URI that was built?

Comment: Check out the answer for this question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query> - which goes into alot of depth explaining what needs quoting and what doesn't ... AND [URIBuilder](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) explains that things get modified ...

Comment: Ohhhh I understand now, you are absolutely right. I didn't realize this are quoted values, I am still quite a junior. If you want to write an answer I will mark it as the answer to this question. Thanks!