# query parameter not in the correct syntax

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, mongodb, express

I am trying to filter a collection by name (or other fields) by checking the url parms and its value e.g

```
http://localhost:3000/patient?filter=name:jack
```

I have a method to retrieve the url pram and convert it to a json object:

```
const filter = handleQueryFilter(req.query.filter)

const handleQueryFilter = (query) => {
    try{
      // convert the string to look like json object
      // example id: -1, name: 1 to { id: "-1"}, {name: "1" }
      const toJSONString = ("{" + query  ).replace(/(\w*[^:].$)/g, (matched => {
       return '"' + matched.substring(0, matched.length ) + '"}'  ;
    }));
      
      return JSON.parse(toJSONString);
    }catch(err){
      return JSON.parse("{}"); // parse empty json if the clients input wrong query format
    }
  }
```

What ever returned from the 'handleQueryFilter' is passed to the 'find' method to get the result from the database

```
let patients = await Patient.find(filter);
```

However handleQueryFilter always returns an empty object (the catch part above), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the / from the URL before query  params `http://localhost:3000/patient?filter=name:jack`

Comment: also `:` is a reserved character at `name:jack` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query

Answer (score 0):

First: make express pasre req.body automatically by using

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Edit you URL to be:
`http://localhost:3000/patient?name=jack`

Comment: the / was a typo, I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Your `replace` operation does not what it is supposed to do:

```js
"{id: -1, name: 1".replace(/(\w*[^:].$)/g, (matched => {
       return '"' + matched.substring(0, matched.length ) + '"}'
}))
```

returns `'{id: -1, name:" 1"}'`, which is not valid JSON, therefore `JSON.parse` gives an error.

Try something like

```js
Object.fromEntries("id: -1, name: 1".split(/,\s*/).map(_=>_.split(/:\s*/)))
```

which returns
`{id: '-1', name: '1'}` without the need for `JSON.parse`.