# Axios Adds Brackets [] To Request Param

Tags: reactjs, axios, parameters

I'm trying to add a list of items as a request parameter. When I manually write the URL like that: `http://localhost:8080/api/user/book/?keyword=&page=1&pageSize=5&field=id&order=ascend&author=aziz&author=nazim`, I get what I want.

However, Axios insists on adding square brackets pointlessly.

```
const _fetchBooks = async (params) => {
        const url = `${UrlUtil.userURL()}/book/`;

        const response = await axios.get(url, {
            params: {
                keyword: params.search,
                page: params.pagination.current,
                pageSize: params.pagination.pageSize,
                field: params.sorter?.field,
                order: params.sorter?.order,
                author: params.filter?.author,
            },
       ...
    };
```

Here's the result URL React trying to reach when I do filtering:
`http://localhost:8080/api/user/book/?keyword=&page=1&pageSize=5&field=id&order=ascend&author[]=aziz&author[]=nazim`

With the brackets, I cannot go on because I get an exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/api/user/book/keyword=&page=1&pageSize=5&field=id&order=ascend&author[]=aziz&author[]=nazim ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986`

So, Java doesn't like the brackets.

Comment: Is `params.filter?.author` an array? If so, it might cause issues.

Comment: Yes, it is an array of String, but it needs to be. Because users can filter multiple authors.

Comment: You could try manually  formatting the string, like `params.filter?.author.join(",")`. Depends on how your backend API works.

Comment: Excellent, I can use that even without changing my API.

Comment: just to note it's not react adding the array, params.filter.author is an array so js in general would be doing this regardless

Comment: React and axios are different things, and that's a standard way to encode array values in a URL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @AndyRay said in the comment, it's not React doing this, its Axios. This is standard behaviour as documented by their API. You can change the way that arrays get serialized using [paramsSerializer option](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

```
const response = await axios.get(url, {
  params: {
    keyword: params.search,
    page: params.pagination.current,
    pageSize: params.pagination.pageSize,
    field: params.sorter?.field,
    order: params.sorter?.order,
    author: params.filter?.author,
  },
  paramsSerializer: { indexes: null }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as I can understand your issue of Invalid character found

**I suggest you to read this first:**

[What's valid and what's not in a URI query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query)

**To solve this issue of using invalid characters such as "[" you need to encode the url params and to do so check this fuction:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

**Example:**

```
const _fetchBooks = async (params) => {
        const url = `${UrlUtil.userURL()}/book/`;

        const response = await axios.get(url, {
            params: {
                keyword: params.search,
                page: params.pagination.current,
                pageSize: params.pagination.pageSize,
                field: params.sorter?.field,
                order: params.sorter?.order,
                author: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params.filter?.author)),
            },
       ...
    };
```

Best of luck ...