Azure Maps rejecting Route Request with ZipCode
When i submit a Zip code as a location to AzureMaps, it returns bad request.
My theory is that the centralized point on the Zipcode is not a navigable point by road.
I've tried a few things:
-Deviation
I added the deviation parameter of 2.5km to the request, but it still returned bad request.
-Snaptoroad api
This api returned as nonexistent. I may have formed the url incorrectly. But either way, looking at the documentation, this is more about visual. The only goal here is to return a travel duration for a route
-Reverse geocoding
Someone suggested reverse geocoding forces Azure to find the nearest navigable address, which i thought was creative, but also didnt work.
Im going to try Snaptoroad api again, but i dont think thats correct. I also have to try fuzzy inputs.
For more context, the method takes in a hubId and a list of locations. "Locations" are typically full or near full addresses, but can be zip codes or cities and states. Commas are not allowed in the parameter.
The return is a simple double of route minutes.
This is all in c# asp core
UPDATE:
Fuzzy search did not work. My method here:
public async Task<double> HubRouteCalculate(DateTime sDate, TimeSpan sTime, string sHub, List<string> sLocations)
{
    // Combine date and time
    var localDateTime = sDate.Add(sTime); // Local time
    var utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));

    // Look up the hub address
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sHub) || sLocations == null || sLocations.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hub or destination addresses.");
    }
    if(sHub.Substring(0,1) != "H") { sHub = "H" + sHub; }
    var hub = _context.ListHubs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.HubId == sHub);
    if (hub == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Hub not found.");
    } //**return error
    //var hubCoordinates = await GeocodeAddress(hub.Address);
    var hubCoordinates = await FuzzySearchAddressGeoCode(hub.Address);

    // Construct waypoints starting and ending at the hub
    // Geocode all destination locations
    var waypointCoordinates = new List<string>
    {
        $"{hubCoordinates.lat},{hubCoordinates.lon}" // Starting point (hub)
    };

    foreach (var location in sLocations)
    {
        //var coordinates = await GeocodeAddress(location);
        //waypointCoordinates.Add($"{coordinates.lat},{coordinates.lon}");
        var coordinates = await FuzzySearchAddressGeoCode(location);
        waypointCoordinates.Add($"{coordinates.lat},{coordinates.lon}");
    }

    waypointCoordinates.Add($"{hubCoordinates.lat},{hubCoordinates.lon}"); // Return to hub

    // Construct the query parameter with all waypoints
    var route = string.Join(":", waypointCoordinates);

    // Construct the Azure Maps Routing API URL
    var url = $"https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions/json?api-version=1.0" +
              $"&query={route}" +
              $"&minDeviationDistance = 100" +
              $"&travelMode=truck" +
              $"&routeType=fastest" +
              $"&vehicleHeight=3.9" +   // Example vehicle dimensions (meters) 13ft => 3.9
              $"&vehicleWidth=2.43" +  //8ft => 2.43
              $"&vehicleLength=10.97" + //36ft => 10.97
              $"&vehicleWeight=11800" + // Example weight (kg) 26000lbs => 11800
              $"&departureTime={Uri.EscapeDataString(utcDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"))}" +
              $"&subscription-key={_azureMapsKey}";

    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Azure Maps API error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            }

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var routeData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AzureMapsRouteResponse>(content);

            // Extract total travel time in seconds and convert to minutes
            var travelTimeInSeconds = routeData.routes[0].summary.travelTimeInSeconds;
            return travelTimeInSeconds / 60.0; // Return travel time in minutes
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Error calculating route: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

The error here:
Error calculating route: Azure Maps API error: BadRequest - Bad Request
The request here:
https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions/json?api-version=1.0&query=40.765073,-73.902279:23.672831,53.745517:40.765073,-73.902279&minDeviationDistance = 100&travelMode=truck&routeType=fastest&vehicleHeight=3.9&vehicleWidth=2.43&vehicleLength=10.97&vehicleWeight=11800&departureTime=2024-12-23T16%3A00%3A39Z&subscription-key=AHqc5ekSrA5PhfZM9joRnP0THz0ub03uGIuqqsy51GYCV8iUFJOLJQQJ99ALACYeBjFLbQ9fAAAgAZMP1RSB

Adjusting fuzzysearch worked once I added the country code. Guess you should follow the documentation recommendations.

Please share a [mcve]. You can't show us sample code that we can't just run and see the issue.

You forgot to url encode the : and , and possibly others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query

The request here: That clearly isn't passing a zip code.

@mjwills you have alot of silly comments that seem like you arent reading the question properly. 1) you should be able to reproduce the problem. the method i provided was to show MY approach, not for you to copy paste. 2) You are 100% wrong and clearly arent familiar with the documentation. otherwise, this wouldnt work if not a zip code... 3) So the purpose is to review the structure of the url. not to read the data. 4) aside, you clearly didnt see my comment that the problem was fixed with the fuzzy search api.

@mjwills I went on a tear because you more exp devs often have unhelpful comments and answers to questions, and it makes this community an unenjoyable place. This is why I havent posted on here for a while. It's really confusing why you more exp devs arent more welcoming and encouraging learning about coding.
I wouldn't be surprised if you deleted these comments I wrote

You are 100% wrong and clearly arent familiar with the documentation. otherwise, this wouldnt work if not a zip code... What specific thing am I wrong about?

aside, you clearly didnt see my comment that the problem was fixed with the fuzzy search api Your question says Fuzzy search did not work. So now I am confused. Did it work, or not?

you should be able to reproduce the problem I can't easily reproduce it _since you didn't provide your inputs (e.g. the zip code). the method i provided was to show MY approach, not for you to copy paste A large benefit of providing code is to make it easy for us to copy and paste it and reproduce it. That is literally why there is a [mcve] shortcut for [mcve]. We can't help you solve a problem if we can't see half of the code involved. e.g. where is FuzzySearchAddressGeoCode?

I went on a tear because you more exp devs often have unhelpful comments and answers to questions You went to the doctor, and the doctor asked for some more details about your symptoms. That isn't unhelpful - that is helpful. You want an instant answer - sure. But that isn't how helping people with code works. We need to actually see enough code to know the context to help you.

It's really confusing why you more exp devs arent more welcoming and encouraging learning about coding. I have you a link teaching you how to ask better questions. I pointed you to a page showing that you need to url encode characters that you aren't encoding. How exactly do you want me to be more welcoming and encouraging? Do a dance? Spend 100 words on "Welcome, it is so great to have you here. etc etc" Something else?

Yes, your code only works when you provide the country code with it and I do agree with that.

@mjwillis you do not encode the ":". 100% wrong.... i said "comment" it was in the comments. Again not reading. As for the doctor, yeah i wouldn't go to a doctor that didnt LISTEN or provide wrong info, like encoding the ":". I expect you to be encouraging by READING rrather than SNIPING. You could have remarked about the fuzzy search working, RithwikBojja did. But you didnt. Your comments as a whole were UNHELPFUL to me and also to the community

100% wrong Dude - it is clearly in the URL you provided. 17:40. There is a colon right there. And it isn't the only one. Again I ask you - which statement of mine was wrong? I say it again - you need to url encode - your var route = string.Join(":", waypointCoordinates); code is not doing that. If you see a : or , in your url, you know you forgot to url encode.

You could have remarked about the fuzzy search working Your question still says Fuzzy search did not work. If that isn't true then update your question.

Yes, your code will work when you provide the country with it . Below is the minimalized code without classes which worked for me:
using System.Text.Json;

class Program
{
    private const string Key_Az_mp = "4DtMNZ90CPDohp7g1fgAZMP41UE";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rithzipCde = "29089";
        List<string> dest_rith_add = new List<string> { "80909", "20901" };

        double gettime = await Rith_Timetakes(rithzipCde, dest_rith_add);
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello Rithwik, The Total time that may take is: {gettime} minutes");

    }

    static async Task<double> Rith_Timetakes(string tstadd, List<string> dest_rith_add)
    {
        using HttpClient ricl = new HttpClient();
        const string rith_cntry_code = "US";

        var tstcrdts = await Rith_Cordinates($"{tstadd}, {rith_cntry_code}", ricl);

        List<string> tstpnts = new List<string> { $"{tstcrdts.lat},{tstcrdts.lon}" };
        foreach (var rith in dest_rith_add)
        {
            var crds = await Rith_Cordinates($"{rith}, {rith_cntry_code}", ricl);
            tstpnts.Add($"{crds.lat},{crds.lon}");
        }
        tstpnts.Add($"{tstcrdts.lat},{tstcrdts.lon}"); 
        string routeQuery = string.Join(":", tstpnts);

        string url = $"https://atlas.microsoft.com/route/directions/json?api-version=1.0&query={routeQuery}&subscription-key={Key_Az_mp}";
        HttpResponseMessage ri_out = await ricl.GetAsync(url);
        ri_out.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string ri_data = await ri_out.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        using JsonDocument cho = JsonDocument.Parse(ri_data);
        double ri_secs = cho.RootElement.GetProperty("routes")[0].GetProperty("summary").GetProperty("travelTimeInSeconds").GetDouble();
        return ri_secs / 60.0; 
    }

    static async Task<(double lat, double lon)> Rith_Cordinates(string address, HttpClient client)
    {
        string ri_uri = $"https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?api-version=1.0&query={Uri.EscapeDataString(address)}&subscription-key={Key_Az_mp}";
        HttpResponseMessage ri_out = await client.GetAsync(ri_uri);
        ri_out.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string ridata = await ri_out.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        using JsonDocument cho = JsonDocument.Parse(ridata);
        JsonElement ri = cho.RootElement.GetProperty("results")[0].GetProperty("position");
        return (ri.GetProperty("lat").GetDouble(), ri.GetProperty("lon").GetDouble());
    }
}

Output:

